# Start new fragment in Swipe tab action bar

Tags: android

I am building my apps with swipe tab action bar.  I manage to build that but I need to start a new fragment when user press something from one of the tab, anyone can help me what can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are in a fragment

The following code is what you need!

```
YourFragment openfragment= new YourFragment();
this.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
.replace(R.id.Layout_container, openfragment,TAG_FRAGMENT)
.addToBackStack(null)
.commit();
```